# How to specify content type as application/json while sending message to azure service bus topic using an Azure Function?

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-queues

I'm using an Azure Function (Python) to send a message to a Service Bus topic whenever a file lands in blob storage following a similar set up to that outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#connections).

In particular, in order to send the message I have this in the JSON file:

```
{
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "AzureServiceBusConnectionString",
      "name": "msg",
      "queueName": "outqueue"
}
```

and in *init*.py file I have `msg.set(input_msg)` where input_msg is a JSON string, the output of doing `json.dumps(list(reader))` on a CSV string.

When this message is picked up by the topic and subscriptions it has content type set to `text/plain`, whilst I'd like this to be `application/json` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads).

Is there a way to set this, for instance when I do `msg.set`, is there a way to specify the content type?

[image]

Full code:
***init*.py**

```
def get_json_content_from_csv(csv_content: str) -> str:
    reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(csv_content))
    json_content = json.dumps(list(reader))
    return json_content

def main(event: func.EventGridEvent, msg: func.Out[str]):
    data = event.get_json()
    url = data["url"]
    input_blob = BlobClient.from_blob_url(url, DefaultAzureCredential())
    csv_content = input_blob.download_blob(encoding='UTF-8').readall()
    json_content = get_json_content_from_csv(csv_content)
    msg.set(json.dumps(json_content))
```

**function.json**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "serviceBus",
      "direction": "out",
      "connection": "AzureServiceBus",
      "name": "msg",
      "topicName": "dev-iris-service-bus-topic"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please share your complete code.

Comment: Full code now added, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to this github issue for the Python SDK:

[Cannot set Service Bus Message ContentType - Github Issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/11751)

The github issue response points to the docs here to set the contentType property on the message class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/uamqp/uamqp.message.messageproperties?view=azure-python

Comment: I think this is when doing it via a http request as opposed to an Azure Function